# Installshield: Which Redistributables do I Need, MSVCR120.dll Not Found

Tags: c++11, visual-studio-2013, installshield, windows-7-x64, windows-10

I am building an application using Visual Studio 2013 in Windows 10. I want to deploy that application on a Windows 7 Machine which is running as a default install. I have tried to add

> Visual C++ 12.0 CRT (x86)

as a dependency in my Install Shield project. There is no option for (Visual C++ 13.0). However, when I go to run the program in Windows 7 I get an error message that states:

> The program can't start because MSVCR120.dll is missing from your
>   computer. Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem.

The C++ code I am using, uses features in the language that are not supported by the MSVC10 compiler, so rebuilding in Visual Studio 2010 is not an option. What option in install shield do I need to select to make the program run in Windows 7?

Comment: You need to add the full c++ 2013 redistributable package x86,  just install it as a part of your installed

Comment: I went ahead and manually installed the 2013 redistributable, and it appends characters to the filename before the file extension. I have also tried to rename those files.

Comment: There is no "Visual C++ 13.0", not the kind of version number that anybody ever picks if they can avoid it.  Just use the DLLs that you tested your program with, you typically find them back in c:\windows\syswow64.  Use the Debug > Windows > Module debugger window if you have no idea.

Comment: @HansPassant Debug > Windows > Module debugger window not available in Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 Professional. I used Dependency Walker to find the dependencies. However, when I run the app on the client machine I get the following error: "The application was unable to start correctly (0xc00007b). Click OK to close the application." Running the app in debug and release on the dev machine indicates it runs normal. The application is a Qt 5.4 app built using Visual Studio 2013's compiler.

Comment: You are copying the wrong DLLs.  The Debug > Windows > Modules debugger window most certainly exists in your VS version.  Ask a team member to look over your shoulder.

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks for not just giving me the fish. I found it. FYI I am doing this solo, and I am a linux developer. Trying to learn Microsoft Technologies.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to add Visual Studio 12.0 (2013) CRT merge modules to your Installshield project, depending of which Installshield version you use (if not included in your version). I'm using Installshield Spring 2012 and in this version Visual Studio 12.0 (2013) merge modules are not directly included. Maybe you are using separeted computers to compile programs and setups like I do.

- You can find those merge modules on your compilation machine( which guarantee the use of the exact same files/dependencies) here:

"C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Merge Modules\Microsoft_VC120_CRT_x64.msm"
or
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Merge Modules\Microsoft_VC120_CRT_x86.msm"

- I copy my personnals merge modules in a specific folder on the Installshield machine.

For exemple:
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\MyMergeModules"

This avoid to install Visual Studio 12.0 (2013) on Installshield machine.

- And configure Installshield to use this folder from Menu:
  Tools -> Options -> Merge Modules Tab -> Merge Modules Location (All Users)
- Then You have to add this merge module to your Installshield project and it should work.

Maybe not the official way but it works for me.